# not able to boot ubuntu after installation of it alongside windows 7 completes!

Tags: installation, boot

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 along side Windows 7 using the **Something Else** option.

1. I had kept 20 GB of unallocated space.
2. After selecting the "Something Else" option, I created a partition of 15 GB with:

   - file system EXT4
   - mount "/"
   - and 5 GB for swap

After installation completed, it asked for a restart, so I did!
But now it only boots into Windows 7. There is no option to start Ubuntu!!

Anybody know about this problem???

Answer (score 0):

Try tapping some keyboard buttons which will show you OS to boot. Different motherboards have different buttons assigned to them. Mine is "space". As I press it on boot it gives me option to choose OS to boot. You can search for yours by searching 'choose OS on startup dual boot'.